# Java SWT Changing Label text on widget selected is not working on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, swt

In my java swt application I have following code. On button select I need to change text of the label twice one is before running thread and other one is after thread finishes. It works on windows but on Mac it does not display the first text. Why this does not work on Mac?

```
button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            statusLabel.setText("Running...");
            Thread background = new Thread() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
               // Long running task
               }
            };
            background.start();
            try {
                background.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            statusLabel.setText("Finished");
        }
    });
```

Comment: `background.join` will block the UI thread and nothing will be updated - you can't wait for threads like this in an SWT app.

Comment: Ok. Even if I remove background.join statusLabel does not display the first text. Do  you know how can I do this?

Comment: Well if you just remove the `join` that code will immediately set the text to Finished. You have trigger the update from the background thread when it finishes using `Display.asyncExec`.

Comment: Ok. But it works fine on Windows.

Comment: You will find that the entire UI is locked up during the long running task even on WIndows.

Comment: I am new to Java application, can you please tell me how can I add trigger update from background thread. Thanks.

Comment: Added answer with suggested code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `Thread.join` is blocking the UI thread which will cause it to stop responding. Exactly how much gets updated before this happens depends on the details on the SWT implementation on each platform.

You should update the UI from the background thread once the code has finished.

Something like:

```
button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

   public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {

      statusLabel.setText("Running...");

      Thread background = new Thread() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            // Long running task

            // Update UI from background thread
            Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() -> statusLabel.setText("Finished"));
         }
      };

      background.start();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I'm adding support for macOS to my SWT app (which I've developed almost entirely on Windows) and couldn't figure out why my UI wasn't updating properly. Thank you for this simple, straightforward solution.